# Is $Y=V(\cos(t),\sin(t),t)\subset k^3$ a variety?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

**Is $Y=V(\cos(t),\sin(t),t)\subset k^3$ a variety?**

I think this is not a variety but I do not know how to prove this rigorously, could someone help me please? How does it look on the $k^3$ plane? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It intersects with the line $x=1, y=0$ infinitely may times, which is impossible for varieties unless it contains the line.